# Write data to specific partitions in Azure Dedicated SQL pool

Tags: apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

At the moment ,we are using steps in the below article to do a full load of the data from one of our spark data sources(delta lake table) and write them to a table on SQL DW.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics
Specifically, the write is carried out using,

```
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "<your-table-name>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .option("maxStrLength",4000).mode("overwrite").save()
```

Now,our source data,by virture of it being a delta lake, is partitioned on the basis of countryid. And we would to load/refresh only certain partitions to the SQL DWH, instead of the full drop table and load(because we specify "overwrite") that is happening now.I tried adding an adding a additional option (partitionBy,countryid) to the above script,but that doesnt seem to work.

Also the above article doesn't mention partitioning.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do this, but this is how I achieved it. If the target Synapse table is partitioned, then we could leverage the "preActions" option provided by the Synapse connector to delete the existing data at that partition. And then we append new data pertaining to that partition(read as a dataframe from source), instead of overwriting the whole data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).